# I'm having trouble with JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm having trouble doing this assignment for codecademy and was wondering if you guys could help me find out what this bug is in the code.

```
confirm("I am ready to play!")
var age = prompt("What's your age");
if(age is > 13)
{
    console.log( "We arent responsible if under age restriction")
}
else 
{
    console.log("Enjoy!")
```

Comment: Don't forget semicolons after each statement!

Comment: also, try running one line / section at a time so you can see where there are problems.

Comment: Also, and this was probably just a copy-paste problem, but don't forget to close your `else` with a `}`.

Comment: [**Learn how to debug JavaScript**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/?hl=en). Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: Besides, the title of the question is completely useless. Nobody is going to search for *"I have troubles with this code"*. Please take the time to read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also need to close the else statement:

```
else 
{
    console.log("Enjoy!")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace  `(age is > 13 )` with `(age > 13)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug your code, open the JavaScript console (F12 on most Windows browsers and Cmd+Shft+I on most Mac browsers) and click on the "Console" tab then refresh the page.

When your code encounters an error, it will be logged there with the error description and line number.

As others have mentioned, remove the "is" from `is < 13`. The "<" symbol is literally interpreted as "is less than", so the "is" word is not used.

Also, you'll need to add semicolons at the end of each statement, and remember to close your conditional code any time you open them.

You'll want to pay close attention to your syntax while you are expanding an outline to real code. A misspelt variable/function or missing punctuation can be very frustrating to deal with when it happens over and over in your code. Every bit of code must be properly formed in syntax without error, or your code will not work.

Answer (score 0):

A complete correct answer:

```
confirm("I am ready to play!");
var age = prompt("What's your age");
if(age > 13) {
  console.log( "We arent responsible if under age restriction");
} else {
  console.log("Enjoy!");
}
```